# Passando parametro dentro do metodo no foreach

Tags: php, lista, foreach

Tenho o index que contem minha chamada da classe `CRUD` e o `foreach` chamando o método da classe `crud`. Porém dentro do `foreach` estou tentando passar o parâmetro do nome da tabela, más ele não mostra nada. Se eu tirar o parâmetro e colocar dentro do método o nome da tabela, funciona de boa. não sei oque eu faço! =/

***Index:***

```
<?php
     require_once('classes/crud.class.php');
     $mostrarpar = new crud();

?>
<?php foreach ($mostrarpar->Listar('moedas_par') as $res) { ?>
     <li><?php echo $res['par_nome']; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

***CRUD:***

```
public function Listar($table) {
    $this->query = $this->setConn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM'.$table.'");
    $this->query->execute();
    return $this->query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: Já experimentou **print_r($res)** ou **var_dump($res)** pra ver essa se resposta tem o que vc quer?

Comment: Tente assim `$this->query = $this->setConn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table);` , estava faltando um espaço entre o nome da tabela e o `FROM`, e a concatenação estava errada

Comment: putz, que erro! hehe, obrigado Augusto. Corrigido e funcionando perfeitamente. ;)